# Unusual String type code in System.TypeCode enum

Tags: c#, string

In the .NET `System.TypeCode` enum, the values are as follows:

```
public enum TypeCode {
  ...
  Double=14,
  Decimal=15,
  DateTime=16,
  String=18,
  }
```

String equals 18.. Why not 17? Where is the logic?

Comment: You assigned it that value. That's the logic.

Comment: If you are asking _why_ the enumeration has been created that way, you need to ask the people who created it.

Comment: Probably compatibility issues

Answer (score 8):

You can assign any number (integer in your case) in any order to enum elements. If value is not assigned explicitely, then by default first value will be `0`. All other values which not assigned exmplicitely will increment previous element's value by one:

```
public enum TypeCode 
{
   Double = 42,
   Decimal, // 43
   DateTime = 0,
   String = 18  
}
```

**UPDATE**

Why `System.TypeCode` has value `17` missing - because there used to be `TimeSpan` type, but [it was removed](http://blogs.ugidotnet.org/adrian/archive/2008/03/17/91755.aspx).